# xv_11 laser_driver tutorial

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to run the xv_11 laser_driver tutorials.  I am trying to run it in Hydro.  I have FTDI cable setup to communicate with the lidar unit.  I have verified that it is putting out information running putty with Windows.  Every time I try to run:

`rosrun xv_11_laser_driver neato_laser_publisher _port:=/dev/ttyUSB0.  I get [ERROR] [1409421260.809415062]: Error instantiating laser object.Are you sure you have the correct port and baud rate? Error was Permission denied.`

Here is a list of my lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 413c:2107 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

It does show the FTDI adapter.

Any help with what I am doing wrong would be very appreciated.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191558/xv_11-laser_driver-tutorial/) by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2014-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is most likely a simple permission problem (as the error states). See if [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/189457/rosrun-as-super-user/#189462) answer (to [Rosrun as super user](http://answers.ros.org/question/189457/rosrun-as-super-user)) helps.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on 2014-08-31**:
Thank you!  That worked perfect.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-08-31**:
Question answered? :)

**Comment by [Frank95000](https://answers.ros.org/users/40594/frank95000/) on 2019-03-23**:
Excuse me, I have the same problem, how did you solve it?